# WordPress - Use first image in post as featured image - for past posts?

Tags: php, wordpress

there are a few solutions and plugins out there that take the first image which is used in a post as featured image.

I need to do that for all the posts which have been in the past. I do not want to open 700 posts and update each of them. Most of the solutions out there only get going when a post has been updated.

Does anybody know how I can add the first image in a post as featured image for past posts automatically?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think This Plugin  solve your problem
https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-featured-image-generator